# React jest mocking useAuth0 Cannot destructure property 'isLoading' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to mock out `useAuth0` from `@auth0/auth0-react` and am running into issues returning a mock value. I currently have a simple provider that uses `useAuth0`

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = props => {
    const {
        isLoading
    } = useAuth0();
    
    return (
        props.children
    )
};
```

This provider is being used in a custom `render` function in my tests

```
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
// Import your own reducer
import applicationsReducer from "../app/slices/applications.slice";
import { UserProvider } from "../user-context";

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    mock,
    store = createStore(applicationsReducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>
              <MockedProvider mocks={mock} addTypename={false}>
                <UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider>
              </MockedProvider>
            </Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

To mock it I've set up a mocks folder using the scoped module documentation from jest

```
--src
   --__mocks__
      --@auth0
         --auth0-react.js
```

The code for that mock looks like this

```
export const withAuthenticationRequired = jest.fn().mockImplementation((component, _) => {
    return component
})

export const useAuth0 = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  error: null,
  isAuthenticated: true,
  isLoading: true,
  user: {},
})
```

The `withAuthenticationRequired` mock works fine, however the `useAuth0` keeps throwing the error
`Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isLoading' of '(0 , _auth0React.useAuth0)(...)' as it is undefined.]`
I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this question! I was stuck for days trying to do the same thing because I didn't know how to setup the folder structure to mock auth0-react!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out, I was missing the `Auth0Provider` in my test utils:

```
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

// Import your own reducer
import applicationsReducer from "../app/slices/applications.slice";
import { UserProvider } from "../user-context";

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    mock,
    store = createStore(applicationsReducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Auth0Provider clientId="__test_client_id__" domain="__test_domain__">
              <Provider store={store}>
                <MockedProvider mocks={mock} addTypename={false}>
                  <UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider>
                </MockedProvider>
              </Provider>
            </Auth0Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```