# How to mock a module that contains a forward slash?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

Mocking a standard npm project is straight forward. Create a `__mocks__` folder adjacent to node_modules folder, then put the name of the package as the file and write the mock contents within.

Example: `/__mocks__/axios.ts`

Where I'm stuck on is having an npm package import that looks like this:
@auth0/auth0-react

How can I mock the contents of this file? I tried creating a file named `@auth0/auth0-react.tsx` but jest doesn't seem to be picking up the mocked file. When I import `import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';` and `console.log(Auth0Provider)`, All I get is the standard `Jest.fn()` attributes.

Here are the contents of the mocked file

```
/* eslint-disable import/prefer-default-export */
export const Auth0Provider = (component: JSX.Element): JSX.Element => component;
```

Since I did not use `jest.fn()` on this one method, I'm expecting `console.log(Auth0Provider)` to show that it contains a function.

In my test code I have `jest.mock('@auth0/auth0-react')` before my test. Any ideas?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution via [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388063/react-jest-mocking-useauth0-cannot-destructure-property-isloading-of-undefined#comment121973407_67388063) by kcarra.

To summarize the answer, I'll answer it with 2 points:

1. The `__mocks__` directory must be in the vicinity of the file being tested. If your file is under /src/MyComponent, then the path for mocks folder should be `/src/__mocks__/`.
2. The folder structure under `__mocks__` must mimc the path as shown in your import. In my scenario, I need to create a folder named `@auth0` and then a file called `auth0-react.tsx` in that folder.

Here's how I structured my test and mocks files.

- mocks: `/src/__mocks__/@auth0/auth0-react.tsx`
- tests: `/src/__tests__/MyComponent.tsx`
- Actual component file: `/src/MyComponent.tsx`